# How to perform sensitivity analysis to a system of ODEs with respect to its own variables.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, initial-value-problems

**The Problem**

I have a very large system of coupled ODEs which is similar to:

$$\begin{multline}
\begin{bmatrix}m_1 & 0 \\ 0 & m_2\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\ddot{x}_1 \\ \ddot{x}_2\end{bmatrix}
+\begin{bmatrix}c_1+c_2 & -c_2 \\ -c_2 & c_2+c_3\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \dot{x}_1 \\ \dot{x}_2\end{bmatrix}
+\begin{bmatrix}k_1+k_2 & -k_2 \\ -k_2 & k_2+k_3\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix}
\\+\begin{bmatrix}g_1 & 0 \\ 0 & g_2\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \sin(\omega t -\phi_1) \\ \sin(\omega t -\phi_2)\end{bmatrix}
=\mathbf{0} 
\end{multline}$$

where in a more compact matrix notation the above becomes:

$$M\ddot{X}+C\dot{X}+KX+G\sin(\omega t - \Phi)=\mathbf{0} \tag{1}$$

Using this equation, I would like to find the sensitivity of variable $\dot{x}_1$ with respect to $\dot{x}_2$, i.e. $\dfrac{\partial \dot{x}_1}{\partial \dot{x}_2}$.

---

**My Attempt**

My fist task is to set equation (1) to first order format by letting $\mathbf{X}=[X,\dot{X}]^T$:

$$\mathbf{\dot{X}}=\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{I} \\ -M^{-1}K & -M^{-1}C \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{X}+\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{0} \\ G\sin(\omega t - \Phi)  \end{bmatrix} \tag{2}$$
$$ \Rightarrow \dot{\mathbf{X}} = \mathbf{F}(t,\mathbf{X}) \tag{3}$$

Then I take the derivative of $\mathbf{\dot{X}}$ with respect to $\dot{x}_2$, such that:

$$\frac{\partial \dot{\mathbf{X}}}{\partial \dot{x}_2} = \frac{\partial\mathbf{F}}{\partial\mathbf{X}}\frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial \dot{x}_2} \tag{4}$$

Where $\frac{\partial\mathbf{F}}{\partial\mathbf{X}} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{I} \\ -M^{-1}K & -M^{-1}C \end{bmatrix}$, i.e. the Jacobian of equation (2).

Thus, equation (4) is another differential equation to be solved for $\frac{\partial \mathbf{X}}{\partial \dot{x}_2}$. Since $\frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial \dot{x}_2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{x}_2}[x_1,x_2,\dot{x}_1,\dot{x}_2]^T$, I can simply extract  $\frac{\partial \dot{x}_1}{\partial \dot{x}_2}$ from that vector. Initially, this approach seems reasonable to me, however in an effort to double-check the logic behind this, I realised that $\frac{\partial\dot{x}_2}{\partial\dot{x}_2}\neq1$, which should not be the case.

As a matter of fact, from [this article's](https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1467-9868.2007.00610.x) equation 6, I found that my equation (4) is actually used to find the sensitivity of the variables *with respect to their initial conditions*. So could anyone explain to me how to find $\frac{\partial\dot{x}_1}{\partial\dot{x}_2}$?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What exactly is $\frac{∂\dot x_1}{∂\dot x_2}$, at what point and how does $\dot x_2$ get changed? At what time is the input, and at what the output? Do you just want the partial derivative of $\dot x_1=F_1(t,X)$ for $X_4=\dot x_2$ (which is zero, as these two state components are independent)?

Comment: I assume that since this is a coupled system of equations, an infitesimal change in $\dot{x}_2$ will also bring about a change in $\dot{x}_1$, hence $\frac{\partial\dot{x}_1}{\partial\dot{x}_2}$ should have some value for every $t$. In this case I just saw what you are saying mathematically, that this partial derivative should be zero. It is however hard to intuitively understand that now that I'm thinking about it. For example would the same hold for let's say $\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial {x}_2}$? By the same logic that should be zero as well right?

Comment: Let's try this another way: Any derivative can be approximated by a difference quotient. What would be an appropriate difference quotient for the sensitivity that you want to compute? What is the change in $\dot x_2$ or $x_2$ and where do you measure the change in $\dot x_1$ or $x_1$?